# Why spline interpolate by repeating p+1 knots?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, curves, spline

By repeating $p+1$ knots in spline, we can let a spline interpolate in a point. This is true but I don't understand why it happens for $p+1$ knots? If I can find somewhere a proof or someone can give a little bit of explanation, it would be great :-)